# Security has disabled my style.css file, how do I connect it back?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

When security is connected, `style.css` is disabled, the console displays the following message:

> No mapping for GET /style.css.

In the browser in the developer panel writes:

> localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/style.css' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."

How can I connect it back? I tried to do something, but it didn 't work.

My configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    Securityhandler successHandler;

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/resources/**", "/css/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/acthasform/", "/resources/**").permitAll();
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/insert", "/delete", "/update", "/create").hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .successHandler(successHandler)
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/403");
    
        return http.build();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `http://localhost:8080/style.css`, it should be `http://localhost:8080/css/style.css`.

Comment: @dur hi! I had a problem even before security was turned on, my style.css file didn't work at all from the css folder, it only worked when I moved it to the static folder, I even asked a question about it on stackoverflow, but I didn't solve this question, so before security was connected, it worked  /static/style.css, and that's how it didn't work /static/css/style.css.    Now the situation has worsened, as security has apparently disabled access to css, I tried to move style.css to the css folder again, so it was added to ignoring(), but it didn't do anything

Comment: Do you have any Spring Web customising? Did you add a mapping for CSS?

Comment: @dur I posted my project on github, if you have time, please, look here https://github.com/se-nata/ATI.git. Additionally, I only registered the static folder in ResourceHandlerRegistry. Yes I added a line <link  th:href="@{/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" /> in /actrelation/insert.html

Comment: Your mapping looks wrong. Read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.static-content Maybe you don't need a mapping at all.

Comment: @dur thank you very much, I'll read the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding the correct pattern to application.properties
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/**.
I also added this pattern to addResourceHandlers

```
 @Override
     public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
         registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/"); 
     }
    }
```

I had it done wrong,but now, that I've added it all, css is connected.